# Crawling Amazon in python using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing a simple crawling project using python. I am trying to write the data into a csv file, but it's not writing anything into the csv file.

I have tried using beautiful soup, but I am completely new to this:

```
def article(self):
 url="https://www.amazon.in/s?i=electronics&bbn=1389401031&rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cp_89%3ASamsung%2Cp_36%3A1318504031&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1560269023&rnid=1318502031&ref=sr_nr_p_36_2"
      a=[]
      r=requests.get(url)
      doc=BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")

      for cards in doc.select(".sg-col-inner"):

          title=cards.select_one(".a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal").text
          price=cards.select_one(".a-size-base").text
          crawled=crawledArticle(title,price)
          a.append(crawled)
      return a 

import csv
fetcher = b()

with open('pro.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    articlewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for article in fetcher.article():
        articlewriter.writerow([article.title,article.price])
```

Yet the csv file stays empty

Comment: What is the function `b()`?

Comment: b is the class name

Comment: Ok...could you show how the class looks like?

Comment: class crawledArticle():
    def __init__(self,title,price):
        self.title=title
        #self.rating=rating
        self.price=price
class b(): 
    
    
    def article(self):

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon has taken measures to prevent scraping, so your method probably won't work most of the time, since Amazon detects you scraping and probably redirects you to a captcha page to verify that you are human before you can scrape the products.

One way around this is to use ***selenium***. Selenium is a browser automater, allowing you to visit pages as if it were done by a person rather that a program.

To use it you must first install selenium:

```py
pip install selenium
```

And you also need to install the driver for your your desired browser (I'm using chrome in this example).

For the chrome driver go to http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and download the correct driver based on your current version of chrome and operating system. Put it in the same folder (directory) as your python program.

Here is the code to scrape the amazon webpage with selenium:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class crawledArticle():
    def __init__(self,title,price):
        self.title=title
        #self.rating=rating
        self.price=price

class b:

    def article(self):
        a = []

        url="https://www.amazon.in/s?i=electronics&bbn=1389401031&rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A976420031%2Cn%3A1389401031%2Cp_89%3ASamsung%2Cp_36%3A1318504031&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1560269023&rnid=1318502031&ref=sr_nr_p_36_2"

        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        browser.get(url)

        count = 1
        while True:
            try:
                title = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[1]/div[' + str(count) + ']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/h2/a/span')
                price = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[1]/div[' + str(count) + ']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/a/span[1]/span[2]/span[2]')

                info = crawledArticle(title.text, price.text)
                a.append(info)

                count += 1

            except: break

        browser.close()

        return a


fetcher = b()

with open('pro.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    articlewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for article in fetcher.article():
        articlewriter.writerow([article.title,article.price])
```

Normally, selenium opens a browser window, but the `options.headless = True` prevents that.

What this does: searches for the titles and prices of the products by their xpaths, puts the info into an instance of `crawledArticle`, and adds it to the list `a[]`. The file `pro.csv` is opened and the info is written to the file.

The xpath of an element is just a way to find it through the hierarchy of the html elements. In chrome you can find it by going to the inspect menu, highlighting your desired element, and right clicking, going to Copy>Copy Xpath. More info [here](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#1)

Here is the contents of pro.csv:

```
Samsung Guru 1200 (GT-E1200, Black);1,100
Samsung Guru Music 2 (SM-B310E, Blue);1,625
Samsung Guru Music 2 (SM-B310E, Black);1,625
Samsung Guru Music 2 SM-B310E (White);1,625
Samsung EO-BG920BFEGIN Bluetooth Headset with mic (Gold);2,399
Samsung Guru 1200 (Gold);1,100
Samsung EVO Plus Grade 3 Class 10 128GB MicroSDXC Memory Card with SD Adapter (MB-MC128GA/IN);1,793
Samsung Guru 1200 (GT-E1200, Indigo Blue);1,100
Samsung Guru Music 2 (Gold);1,625
Samsung Guru FM Plus (SM-B110E/D, Dark Blue);1,375
Samsung Guru 1200 (GT-E1200, White);1,100
Samsung EO-BG920BBEGIN Bluetooth Wireless in-Ear Headphones with mic(Black-Sapphire);2,699
Samsung Guru FM Plus (SM-B110E/D, Black);1,375
Samsung Guru FM Plus (Gold);1,375
Samsung EO-BG950CBEGIN Bluetooth Wireless in-Ear Flexible Headphones with Microphone (Black);3,580
Samsung Guru FM Plus (SM-B110E/D, White);1,375
Samsung Metro 350 (Gold);3,070
Samsung Level U Bluetooth Stereo Headset Flexible Joint With Neckband ( Gold );2,479
```

---

Info on selenium ---

Official website: https://www.seleniumhq.org

Unofficial docs (quite useful): https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: No problem. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helped you

Comment: what do you mean by x path?

Comment: The `xpath` of an element is just a way to find it through the hierarchy of the html elements. In chrome you can find it by going to the inspect menu, highlighting your desired element, and right clicking, going to Copy>Copy Xpath. More info [here](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html#1)